# How much grass seed is too much?

Tags: lawn, grass, lawn-repair, overseeding, yard

I'm told by my seed supplier that it's impossible to to put down too much seed when overseeding an existing lawn or seeding a new lawn for the first time.  Assuming the cost of seed is not an issue, is it possible to put down too much seed?

Answer (score 3):

Sure- when you start stacking seed on seed, so some seeds don't have ground contact, it's clearly too much.